# How to Save/Retrieve List<XmlRpcStruct> To/From SQL Database

Tags: c#

I am trying to retrieve data from an API that is throttled. The api allows me to retrieve 10,000 records and then applies the throttling.

I am looping through, increasing the page number, each time to get the next 1000 records.

At some point the api throws me out with an error.

At this point I have incomplete data stored in a

```
List<XmlRpcStruct>
```

I want to be able to wait for the throttling limit to be lifted and then start calling the API from the next page number before the throttling happened.

While I am waiting, I want to store the current List in a database table. And when I start calling the API, retrieve this data, and continue appending to it.

I am calling a number of different reports which produce different "shape" results.

I cannot think of the best way to store this in the database as a field so I can pull it back out into a List later to continue appending to it.

What would be the best database field type to store it as and how would I convert it to that dataype and back to a List

Can anyone suggest how to the above or, possibly, a more elegant way of doing it please?

Any guidance would be very much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: what you need is an XML data type column in SQL Server and srialization / deserialization .NET <-> SQL Server, open this page and scroll down to scenario 1 section for an example: http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/28151.using-xml-serialization-with-c-and-sql-server.aspx